# Writing query that gets information from multiple tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I get an error when I try and run my query and I can't figure out why. This is the last step of my homework, and ive been trying to figure it out for a while now. The query that I am trying to write is.

```
List the country name, it’s population, and the sum of the populations of all cities in   
that country. Add a fourth field to your query that calculates the percent of urban 
population for each country. (For the purposes of this example, assume that the sum of the 
populations of all cities listed for a country represent that country’s entire urban 
population.) Order the results of this query in increasing order of urban population 
percentage.
```

the error that I am receiving right now is

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "cnt.population" must appear in the 
GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 2
```

The code that I have for this is

```
$query ="SELECT cnt.name AS country_name, 
cnt.population AS total_population, 
SUM(cty.population)/(cnt.population) * 100 AS urban_percentage
FROM     what.country cnt 
JOIN     what.city cty ON cty.country_code = cnt.country_code 
GROUP BY cnt.name 
ORDER BY 3 ASC";
```

The two tables that I am using are

```
Table "what.country"
     Column      |         Type          |               Modifiers              
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 country_code    | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 name            | character varying(52) | not null default ''::character varying
 continent       | continent             | not null
 region          | character varying(26) | not null default ''::character varying
 surface_area    | real                  | not null default 0::real
 indep_year      | smallint              | 
 population      | integer               | not null default 0
 life_expectancy | real                  | 
 gnp             | real                  | 
 gnp_old         | real                  | 
 local_name      | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying
 government_form | character varying(45) | not null default ''::character varying


    Table "what.city"
    Column    |         Type          |                     Modifiers                    
--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------
 id           | integer               | not null default nextval('city_id_seq'::regclass)
 name         | character varying(35) | not null default ''::character varying
 country_code | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 district     | character varying(20) | not null default ''::character varying
  population   | integer               | not null default 0
```

Comment: When you use a `GROUP BY` clause you have to tell how the values that are not grouped are going to be aggregated.  This is the case with `cnt.population`.

Comment: @ForguesR How do I do this?

Comment: Figured it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAX for city population as you are doing GROUP BY on city name, there will be only one value for population for that city

```
  $query ="SELECT cnt.name AS    country_name, 
   Max(cnt.population) AS   total_population, 
   SUM(cty.population),  SUM(cty.population)/max(cnt.population) * 100 AS urban_percentage
    FROM     what.country cnt 
    JOIN     what.city cty ON   cty.country_code = cnt.country_code 
    GROUP BY cnt.name";
```